# implement facebook like button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-listview, facebook-like

I created an android app to show comments of certain post from `facebook`.
what I want to do is to implement the `like` button.
I have all the necessary data (facebook token, user id, app id etc.) and permission i need from the user.

circle number **1** is the content of the comment
circle number **2** is the name if the user
circle number **3** is the like button that i want to implement
circle number **4** is the time that the comment sent

[image]

I use this link to get the comments:
https://graph.facebook.com/568609876496765/comments

it returns a `JSON` Object that i phrase and get the data and show it in a `List View`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike webpages, you cannot add a Facebook **Like** button to an Android app. However, you can add the function to Like a post (a Comment in your case) by using "POST" or a "DELETE" query to the Facebook API:

Here is a complete functioning example of what I do to *Toggle* the Like Status of a Comment in my application:

**NOTE: This code is for the older v2.x SDK. So you will need to adapt a few things that are specific to the latest v3.x SDK**

On the onClickListener you will use to post / remove a Like, run this piece of code:

```
try {
    String query = "SELECT user_likes FROM comment WHERE post_id= \'"
            + THE_COMMENT_ID + "\'";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
    String fqlResponse = Utility.mFacebook.request(params);

    JSONArray JALikes = new JSONArray(fqlResponse);

    for (int j = 0; j < JALikes.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject JOTemp = JALikes.getJSONObject(j);

        if (JOTemp.has("user_likes"))   {
            String userLikeStatus = JOTemp.getString("user_likes");
            if (userLikeStatus.equals("true"))  {

                try {
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    Utility.mFacebook.request(arrayComments.get(position).getCommentID() + "/likes", parameters, "DELETE");

                    // CHANGE THE TEXT OF THE WIDGET TO SHOW THE TOGGLED STATE
                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (userLikeStatus.equals("false")) {
                try {
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    Utility.mFacebook.request(arrayComments.get(position).getCommentID() + "/likes", parameters, "POST");

                    // CHANGE THE TEXT OF THE WIDGET TO SHOW THE TOGGLED STATE
                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the first part of the code (**before the `for loop`**), I check the current status if the Logged in user likes the Comment. Based on the result (**in the `for loop`**), I either remove the Like or I post a Like.

Although it is an older SDK, the code is still valid, and with a few modifications (if necessary) will work just fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer but theres two problems in it. first, the call mFacebook.request(params); should be in another thread.
second, the line new JSONArray(fqlResponse); return empty data (returns "[]"). do you know how can i fix that?

Comment: @ShalomMelamed: You can put this code in an `AsyncTask` if that is what you mean. And if the you are getting empty data you should check the query in the Graph Explorer (FQL Query section). It runs just fine. You can also try removing the _escape slash_

Comment: I'm using the facebook Graph Explorer and I moved the code to asyncTask by still the fql response when I remove the escape slash is: {"error_code":601,"error_msg":"Parser error: unexpected '_1982451' at position 60.","request_args":[{"key":"query","value":"SELECT user_likes FROM comment WHERE post_id=568609876496765_1982451"},{"key":"method","value":"fql.query"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}

Comment: @ShalomMelamed: The comment id is a String and needs escape "" or '' surrounding it. Try the query first in the Graph Explorer to be sure.

Comment: I'm cheking the query first in the graph explorer but now I see that it returns an empty data as before (returns "[]")
thanks for your patience.