# Facebook Graph API unlike a liked post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a method in my app that allows the user to "like" a post in his/her news feed. It's done with a simple graph request using `HttpMethod.POST`. But when I try to do an "unlike" action using `HttpMethod.DELETE`, I get an error callback:

```
02-08 00:35:57.298: I/Detail(2628): {Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: 
{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) 
Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application}, isFromCache:false}
```

Now I assume this has something to do with the latest attempt to make all apps that integrate with Facebook use all Facebook looking dialogs and styles, but I could be wrong. Here's the [roadmap post](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/) that has me suspicious:

> Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API  We will
>   remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph
>   API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is
>   different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
>   target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you
>   want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the
>   feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or
>   action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the
>   friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong, or is Facebook just ruining me? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using to run the request.

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Utility.fbSession, null, null, null, new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        String responseString = response.toString();
        Log.i("Detail", responseString);
        updateDetail();
    }
});
HttpMethod nextLikeCall = HttpMethod.DELETE;
likeRequest.setHttpMethod(nextLikeCall);
likeRequest.setGraphPath(itemId+"/likes");
likeRequest.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me. Except, I am using the older SDK V 2.x. I had posted an answer on a question yesterday for Liking and "Unliking" comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14749927/450534. See if it works for you. You will have to change the Comments specific parts but the code is the same for posts as well as comments.

Comment: It seems to be a permissions issue based on the error code, but I have publish_stream permission set.

Comment: Have you tried your exact requests in the graph explorer? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer The scenario you described should work.

Comment: I get the same response in the graph explorer. POST (like) works fine, but DELETE (unlike) gives me the error.

Comment: @Wenger did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same problem.  Liking works fine, but unliking throws this same error.

Comment: @Wenger actually figured it out, check my answer below.  Im not an android guy, but I threw in some Objective-C code to give you an idea of what needs to be done.  The ultimate solution to your question is pretty easy, but might need to hack a bit to get there.

Answer (score 1):

When you grab the post id from the graph data, it should be in a format like:  XXXXX_YYYYY.  The XXXXX is simply the users id and YYYYY is the actual post id.  What you need to do is extract and use just the YYYYY portion of the post id that graph gives you.  so instead of graph.facebook.com/XXXXX_YYYYY/likes.... you want to send graph.facebook.com/YYYYY/likes.  This will work with both liking and unliking, you can test in graph explorer first before hacking together a substring extraction method.

Not sure how to extract a section of a string on Android, but I know in Objective-C/iOS, it can be done like this (code not tested, for reference/idea) :

```
SString *actualPostIdStr;      //The String we will put the actual postId in
NSString *oldIdStr          =   //<the string in format XXXXX_YYYYY>
NSInteger charCount         =   [oldIdStr length]; //get the length of the original XXXXX_YYYYY string
NSRange fRangeCount         =   [oldIdStr rangeOfString:@"_"]; //get count of characters to remove (XXXXXX)


if (fRangeCount.location != NSNotFound){
    NSInteger startingPos   =   fRangeCount.location + 1; //get the starting character position of the actual postId
    actualPostIdStr         =   [[oldIdStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startingPos, charCount - startingPos)] copy];
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Ok, so I have been playing around with likes all day... It seems that this method sometimes doesn't work, but it all depends on the type of graph object which you are attempting to like/unlike.  For example... plain status posts, this method works perfectly.  However, I ran into a problem when trying to like a photo with a message/story post object.  It turns out, in the graph data for this type of post object with photo, there is an additional paramter called "object_id", in addition to the plain "id" that is in status post graph data.  in this case, with the photo and story post, you need to pass the "object_id", unaltered for successful unliking.

This mess seems like either a bug on FB's end, or they are making changes and disallowing likes/unlikes from graph api & just forgot/haven't to told us yet :)  hopefully the former.  In the mean time, you're just going to have to use my above answer, but just make sure you test with as many different types of post objects you can find, and use if conditions when a different id (portion of "id"... "object_id"... etc) is required.

Comment: That kinda makes sense. I'll have to try it tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Right. "object_id" is where you go to get the high resolution data and other details for the photo that's linked to that given post. I guess that does make sense then to use that instead of the post id.

Comment: @Wenger yeah, but depending on what calls your making, there are a lot of objects that only have "id" with no "object_id"... I've been using the above with a condition to preferably grab "object_id" & fall back to extracting the useful part of "id", and it's been working perfectly so far.  let me know if this works on your end when you get a chance to check.

Comment: Yeah I'm having other issues at the moment (getting rid of my splash screen makes it a nightmare to figure out authentication). But once I get through that I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes *Daniel McCarthy*'s method don't work. In this case we need get Graph API request XXX_YYYY, find field **object_id** and unlike this object_id fid.