# Android:Delete likes and comments using facebook graph api. Updated code required

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using following code to unlike a post from facebook using graph api

```
 if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            String response;
            try {
                response = facebook.request(objectId+"/likes", new Bundle(),"DELETE");
                System.out.println(response);
                if(response.equals("true")){
                    response_returned =true;
                    return response_returned;
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(activity,response , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

It was working fine before but now i am getting following error :

**message":"(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}**

I am using facebook old sdk and i can't switch to new one since a lot of work has been done so is there a work around to unlike comment using old sdk .

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the new SDK so it seems to be an issue with the Graph API in general. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766499/facebook-graph-api-unlike-a-liked-post

Comment: I know but there must be a work around.

Comment: Publishing posts on other user’s walls via API has been disabled with the February 2013 changes. The error message seems to suggest that this affects deleting likes for other users also. You could try to verify that using the Graph API Explorer – if the same request fails in there too with the same error message, than it has nothing to do with your SDK version at all.

Comment: So does it mean that it is impossible now ?